Connection properties of a single stone on an infinite Hex board
This includes a series of questions.
One of the most typical examples is shown as the picture below.

An half-infinite Hex board with an one row of black stones. Black stones are separated by one white stone. Can black connect the two parts of black stones, which means this white stone is trapped in a finite area, or the white stone can escape infinitely far?
One similar but weaker problem:
Ladder escape problem:
Can black connect the two parts?

Until now, my special-trained KataHex(a Hex AI based on alphazero-like algorithm) think black can not connect with a board width of 51.

More questions:
1. What if there are more white stones initially?

2. The angle of the above examples are 180°, if the answers are white wins, can black win if the angle is smaller?

One known result(verified using Mohex): minimum area to trap a single stone on 120° angle:

One conjecture:
No matter how many white stones initially, black wins if angle<180°, white wins if angle>=180°.
3. For arbitrarily large N, does N-th edge template exists?
N-th edge template is the minimum area to connect one stone to the edge at a distance of N-1.
Example: 6-th row edge template

More information can be found in HexWiki:
https://www.hexwiki.net/index.php/Category:Edge_templates
If exists, what is the minimum width f(N) of the template? How fast does f(N) growth?
It has been proved that the minimum width 2~7th edge template are f(2)=2 f(3)=4 f(4)=7 f(5)=10 f(6)=14 f(7)=17, which can be found at HexWiki: https://www.hexwiki.net/index.php/Edge_templates_with_one_stone
I trained a special KataHex for this problem, and got some results not strict but very sure: f(8)=26, f(9)=35, f(10)=44 (f(10) is not quite sure)
The two pictures below are analyzing 8th edge template using KataHex, indicating f(8)=26


4.Unstoppable patterns
For the following 3 pictures, can black reach the red line? And can white reach the blue line?
If both of black and white cannot, then they are called "unstoppable patterns". Are there any other unstoppable patterns other than these three?




More information which may be helpful
Switchback strategy of "ladder escape problem"
There is a strategy to force the ladder turn to left, then the upper-right part become unreachable (red line).


If there is an extra stone very far from the edge. I guess this strategy can be used for multiple times and finally reaches the extra stone, then the two part can be connected. But it's not obvious because when using the switchback the second time, it is a terraced ladder at 2nd/4th rows now. So black has more choices (picture).


See also the open questions at the end of "Infinite Hex is a Draw" JD Hamkins and D Leonessi, https://math.colgate.edu/~integers/xg6/xg6.pdf. Your question is similar to our trapezoid questions.

In particular, do you know the answer when the angle is 90 degrees? This amounts essentially to an open question in our paper.

It is also open whether Red wins on the full infinite board with the advantage of a single extra stone, or even finitely many stones, or indeed much more. If even weak versions of your conjecture are true, you will settle several open questions.

The 90 degree version is relevant for us with arbitrarily long middle segments. If Black can always connect those sides, then our construction shows that there is no finite advantage in infinite Hex.

@JoelDavidHamkins I have read your paper and found your trapezoid questions. However I have no idea how to solve these questions. The only thing I can do is training KataHex for some specific openings. It seems to show that the critical point is 180°. With one extra black stone even on 10th row will help black win the game

Theorem 13 in our paper provides proof that with angle of less than 90, Black can connect, even with arbitrarily large white middle segment. This is the main idea of the proof that with the strong win condition, there is no finite advantage.

Although an angle θ<90° can be embedded in "trangular board", some angle patterns θ≥60° seems to be not able to embedded into a trangular board, because the pattern cannot be rotated arbitrarily due to the board grid

Yes, the argument is with approximations to the angle.

Another question in the vicinity of your questions is the infinite Hex analogue of the Angel and Devils game. Namely, given a single white stone on a full infinite board. Can White escape this stone to infinity?

@JoelDavidHamkins White can escape to infinity if there are no extra black stones. No matter where black plays, white can just play symmetrically.(proved by Bobson in discord server). But this proof can't work if there are any extra black stones.

Ah, that is very nice.

It seems that our arguments in section 6 show that white can win your board, with arbitrarily narrow angles, in the version of the game where white plays two stones each turn for one black stone (even infinitely often playing only one-for-one).

@hzy Regarding the known result you mention in #2, you mean that your software's strategy won against all possible strategies within that board area? Also, in that case of an angle of 120 degrees, could you tweak the input in your first position to start with a width of 2 (or 3) white stones? It would also be interesting to see if your software finds more advantage in starting from a wider base of from a longer initial chain.

For the existence of n-templates, I understand you trained KataHex on a board of a certain size: is it feasible to explicitly play this KataHex's strategy for Black against all possible strategies for White on such boards? I used to suspect that the board geometry prevents the existence of larger templates, and it would be interesting if you could verify your results.

It's impossible to exhaustive enumerate all white strategies. NN-based AI is good at handling positions which AI have not trained, if it has seen some similar positions. So a lot of useless branches are cut.

For 120 degrees with 2 white stones, the minimum board size for black to win may be larger than 19. Not very affordable. Maybe I will try it later.
